# 'Resource temporarily unavailable' and empty folders when attempting to access Windows 7 network share from OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, osx-mountain-lion

I've been having problems using a Windows 7 share in Mac OS X Mountain Lion. After running something fairly intensive like compiling code on the network share I got 'Resource temporarily unavailable' error messages and some folders would appear to be empty in Finder.

Why is this happening, and what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Windows 7's default configuration is not intended for intensive use of network shares.

I fixed the problem using the information in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232271. Setting the 'size' registry value to 3 in:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters\

and then restarted Windows 7.